# How to stop receiving an error reading iCal invitations on Mac sent from Thunderbird?

Tags: macos, thunderbird, apple-mail, calendar.app, icalendar

When I open an iCal invitation (`Mail Attachment.ics` file) in Mac Mail.app sent to me from someone using Thunderbird, I receive the following error:

[image: iCal Error]

The only solution that I've found to date is to save the `Mail Attachment.ics` file somewhere like the Desktop, open it in a text editor, and delete the blank lines at the beginning and end of the file. This problem appears to only happen when I'm receiving invitations from people using Thunderbird under Windows.

- Does anyone know of a better way to solve this problem?
- Is this a bug in Apple iCal, or is Thunderbird not meeting the iCal spec?

#### Configuration Information

- OS: Mac OS X 10.6.2
- Mail Program: Mac Mail.app ver. 4.2 (1077)
- Calendar Program: Mac iCal.app ver 4.0.1 (1374)

Answer (score 0):

Try to write a mail-rule for thunderbird invitations in mail and as the action of the rule delete the empty lines with a script.

Comment: I did find the same idea as your solution implemented using Automater at http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20091215080321140